# Java Eclipse is not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed Java eclipse & JDK on windows 10, but its not starting.

Every time it starts I get a message : An error has occured. See the log file..

This is the latest log file..

```
!SESSION 2018-01-29 01:50:34.036 ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000 java.version=9.0.4 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-01-29 01:50:34.500 !MESSAGE Startup error !STACK 1 java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450) 
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)  ... 10 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The System Bundle could not be resolved: Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.checkSystemState(BaseStorage.java:827)

at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:800)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)    ... 12 more
```

Plz help..

Comment: Which version have you instaled?

Comment: Also you might find an Eclipse expert here, but it seems that tech help like this would be best found on their own forums.  But it's Sunday so you might not get a response until tomorrow.  In the mean time, see if your JDK is installed correctly by following this command line tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html  Check the "common problems" at the end of the contents list on the left.  Then if that works try another IDE as suggested, it will at least let you make some progress today.

Comment: You are using an outdated version of Eclipse from 2013 (`eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000` means Eclipse Kepler/4.3) which does not support Java 9 (`java.version=9.0.4`). Use Eclipse Oxygen.2 instead.

Comment: @howlger how do you know that?

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic Reading the log actually helps. Like this part `eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000 java.version=9.0.4`.

Comment: you guys are awesome..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Eclipse` is way behind your `JDK`. I recommend downloading `Eclipse` from [Eclipse Download](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) corresponding to your system. This will most probably solve your woes.